# tidying igraph plot and routing or TSP question

Tags: r, routes, igraph, dijkstra, traveling-salesman

I have less experience in R and I need help tidying my plot as it looks messy. Also, my project is to find the best minimal route from Seoul to every city and back to Seoul. It is almost like Traveling Salesman Problem (TSP) but there are some cities needed to be visited more than once as it is the only way to reach certain cities. I don't know how to do and what packages to use.

This is my code for igraph plot

```
library(igraph)

g1 <- graph( c("Seoul","Incheon","Seoul","Goyang","Seoul","Seongnam","Seoul",
              "Bucheon","Seoul","Uijeongbu","Seoul","Gimpo",
              "Seoul","Gwangmyeong", "Seoul", "Hanam","Seoul", "Guri",
              "Seoul","Gwacheon","Busan","Changwon","Busan","Gimhae",
              "Busan","Jeju","Busan","Yangsan","Busan","Geoje",
              "Incheon","Goyang","Incheon","Bucheon","Incheon","Siheung",
              "Incheon","Jeju","Incheon","Gimpo","Daegu","Gumi",
              "Daegu","Gyeongsan","Daegu","Yeongcheon","Daejeon",
              "Cheongju","Daejeon","Nonsan","Daejeon","Gongju",
              "Daejeon","Gyeryong","Gwangju","Naju","Suwon","Yongin",
              "Suwon","Seongnam","Suwon","Hwaseong","Suwon","Ansan",
              "Suwon","Gunpo","Suwon","Osan","Suwon","Uiwang",
              "Ulsan","Yangsan","Ulsan","Gyeongju","Ulsan","Miryang",
              "Yongin","Seongnam","Yongin","Hwaseong","Yongin","Pyeongtaek",
              "Yongin","Gwangju-si","Yongin","Icheon","Yongin","Anseong",
              "Yongin","Uiwang","Goyang","Gimpo","Goyang","Paju","Goyang",
              "Yangju","Changwon","Gimhae","Changwon","Jinju","Changwon",
              "Miryang","Seongnam","Gwangju-si","Seongnam","Hanam","Seongnam",
              "Uiwang","Seongnam","Gwacheon","Hwaseong","Ansan","Hwaseong",
              "Pyeongtaek","Hwaseong","Gunpo","Hwaseong","Osan","Cheongju",
              "Cheonan","Cheongju","Sejong","Bucheon","Siheung","Bucheon",
              "Gwangmyeong","Ansan","Anyang","Ansan","Siheung","Ansan",
              "Gunpo","Namyangju","Uijeongbu","Namyangju","Chuncheon",
              "Namyangju","Hanam","Namyangju","Guri","Cheonan","Pyeongtaek",
              "Cheonan","Sejong","Cheonan","Asan","Cheonan","Anseong",
              "Jeonju","Gimje","Gimhae","Yangsan","Gimhae","Miryang",
              "Pyeongtaek","Asan","Pyeongtaek","Osan","Pyeongtaek","Anseong",
              "Pyeongtaek","Dangjin","Anyang","Siheung","Anyang","Gwangmyeong",
              "Anyang","Gunpo","Anyang","Gwacheon","Siheung","Gwangmyeong",
              "Siheung","Gunpo","Pohang","Yeongcheon","Pohang","Gyeongju",
              "Jeju","Gimpo","Jeju","Mokpo","Jeju","Seogwipo","Uijeongbu",
              "Yangju","Uijeongbu","Pocheon","Paju","Yangju","Gumi","Gimcheon",
              "Gumi","Sangju","Gwangju-si","Hanam","Gwangju-si","Icheon",
              "Gwangju-si","Yeoju","Sejong","Gongju","Wonju","Chungju",
              "Wonju","Jecheon","Wonju","Yeoju","Jinju","Sacheon", "Yangsan",
              "Miryang","Asan","Gongju","Iksan","Gunsan","Iksan","Nonsan",
              "Iksan","Gimje","Chuncheon","Pocheon","Gyeongsan","Yeongcheon",
              "Gunpo","Uiwang","Suncheon","Yeosu","Suncheon","Gwangyang",
              "Gunsan","Gimje","Gyeongju","Yeongcheon","Geoje","Tongyeong",
              "Osan","Anseong","Yangju","Pocheon","Yangju","Dongducheon",
              "Icheon","Anseong","Icheon","Yeoju","Mokpo","Naju","Chungju",
              "Jecheon","Chungju","Yeoju","Chungju","Mungyeong","Gangneung",
              "Donghae","Gangneung","Sokcho","Seosan","Dangjin","Andong",
              "Yeongju","Pocheon","Dongducheon","Gimcheon","Sangju","Tongyeong",
              "Sacheon","Nonsan","Gongju","Nonsan","Boryeong","Nonsan",
              "Gyeryong","Gongju","Boryeong","Gongju","Gyeryong","Jeongeup",
              "Gimje","Yeongju","Mungyeong","Yeongju","Taebaek","Sangju",
              "Mungyeong","Sokcho","Samcheok","Samcheok","Taebaek",
              "Suncheon","Gwangju"), directed=F)

E(g1)$distance <- c(27, 16, 20, 19, 20, 24, 14, 20, 15, 15, 36, 18, 299, 18, 53,
                    25, 8, 12, 440, 18, 36, 13, 33, 33, 31, 26, 15, 20, 13, 20,
                    19, 18, 13, 16, 10, 33, 36, 51, 24, 31, 28, 21, 23, 27, 22,
                    11, 12, 24, 18, 52, 27, 11, 13, 19, 13, 14, 34, 20, 23, 38,
                    18, 12, 9, 12, 7, 10, 19, 53, 11, 8, 20, 27, 11, 26, 24, 18,
                    33, 25, 18, 15, 44, 14, 12, 4, 5, 12, 12, 37, 21, 458, 146,
                    27, 10, 23, 24, 21, 36, 14, 23, 36, 21, 39, 33, 26, 20, 32, 
                    40, 20, 29, 18, 47, 24, 4, 27, 19, 22, 29, 17, 24, 18, 13, 
                    32, 18, 37, 28, 43, 51, 33, 56, 20, 28, 12, 30, 38, 29, 47,
                    17, 47, 22, 26, 46, 51, 20, 10, 36,63)

plot(g1, edge.label=E(g1)$distance, 
     vertex.label.cex=0.6, vertex.size=4)
```

[igraph plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0G45.png)

Comment: please state what you have already tried. There are multiple packages (can be found using a search) that can solve a TSP. Which ones have you already tried, and why did they not lead to the desired output?

Comment: I tried networking my data to check if TSP can be applied. However, from the igraph plot I did, some cities need to be visited more than once (TSP technically cant be applied) to find the best route to every city. Also, looking at my igraph plot, it is very messy and it is hard to see the network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using trick from https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/5555/tsp-with-repeated-city-visits

```
library(data.table)
library(purrr)
library(TSP)
library(igraph)
```

We need to create distance matrix based on shortest paths for each pair of vertices:

```
vertex_names <- names(V(g1))
N <- length(vertex_names)

dt <- map(
  head(seq_along(vertex_names), -1), 
  ~data.table(
    from = vertex_names[[.x]],
    to = vertex_names[(.x+1):N],
    path = map(
      shortest_paths(g1, vertex_names[[.x]], vertex_names[(.x+1):N])[["vpath"]], 
      names
    )
  ),
) %>%
  rbindlist()
```

then we calculate distances of shortest paths:

```
m <- as_adjacency_matrix(g1, type = "both", attr = "distance", sparse = FALSE)
dt[, weight := map_dbl(path, ~sum(m[embed(.x, 2)[, 2:1, drop=FALSE]]))]
```

now we assemble new matrix:

```
dt <- rbind(
  dt, dt[, .(from = to, to = from, path = map(path, rev), weight = weight)]
)

new_m <- matrix(0, N, N)
rownames(new_m) <- colnames(new_m) <- vertex_names
new_m[as.matrix(dt[, .(from,to)])] <- dt[["weight"]]
```

on this new matrix we use some heuristic to solve TSP (for exact solution you should use `method="concorde"`):

```
res <- new_m %>%
  TSP() %>%
  solve_TSP(repetitions = 1000, two_opt = TRUE)
```

now we exchange each pair of consecutive cities with shortest path:

```
start_city <- "Seoul"

path_dt <- c(start_city, labels(cut_tour(res, start_city)), start_city) %>%
  embed(2) %>%
  .[,2:1,drop = FALSE] %>%
  "colnames<-"(c("from", "to")) %>%
  as.data.table()
path_dt <- dt[path_dt, on = .(from ,to)]

my_path <- c(unlist(map(path_dt[["path"]], head, -1)), start_city)
```

`my_path` is heuristic solution with distance `tour_length(res)`

Comment: Hello, I continued my codes with your codes. However, I received this error. Is there anything I need to change from your code?

```
Error in `map()`:
ℹ In index: 1.
ℹ With name: Seoul.
Caused by error in `data.table()`:
! object 'to' not found
```

Comment: I've made some changes, now it should work